# How to put bird-style literate Haskell code blocks into a markdown enumeration with pandoc

Tags: markdown, pandoc, literate-programming

Normal markdown code blocks can be part of a list:

````
 *  Item1
 *  Item 2

    ```haskell
    instance Alternative Facts where …
    ```

    more explanation

        instance Alternative Syntax where …

    even more explanation
````

But if I use [pandoc’s `markdown+lhs` mode](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#literate-haskell-support), and I want the code blocks to be rendered within the indented lists, this does not seem to work:

```
 *  Item 3

    Still indented

    > Not picked up by GHC as literate haskell

    More text

> Picked up by GHC, but not indented by pandoc

    Even more text of the item, but rendered as a code-block by pandoc.
```

How can I mark it up so that GHC sees the bird-style code block, but indents it appropriately and also continues the item afterwards?

(Using `\begin{code}…\end{code}` is not an option in this case.)

Comment: Also see https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/3410

Comment: downvoting without commenting  why?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I mark it up so that GHC sees the bird-style code block, but indents it appropriately and also continues the item afterwards?

Note at all, as [confirmed by pandoc’s author](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/3410) and [now noted in the documentation](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/commit/ed4f84e84b1f7e498850e7948e625c7832286f74).